# _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) but my table has only 2 columns

Tags: python, csvreader

My CSV file has only two columns, but it reports when it uses csv_reader to load the data:

```
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

Each row only has two columns, delimited by tab key.

Does the 'fields' mean the same as 'columns' of the table? Or the "fileds" means the count of rows in the file.

I want to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: The error message is saying that one of the values (a column in a specific row) is too large.